# Ошибка error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to size_t strlen(const char*)'

Tags: c++

Вот сам код, ошибка в строке
 9

```
int k1, k2, n;
stringstream sn;
string s;

cin >> n;
sn << n;
s = sn.str();

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s) / 2; ++i) 
    k1 += s[i];
```

Работаю в Code::Blocks, компилятор GNU GCC.

Comment: Ну так а почему вы вообше решили, что можно делать `strlen(s)`?

Answer (score 1):

Ну прямо стыдно отвечать на такое...

```
strlen(s)
```

Посмотрите описание - это для `char*`, для `string` используйте `s.length()`.

Компилятор, кстати, вам все четко указал - что первый аргумент `strlen`... и так далее - простите, но вы читали что он написал?

Comment: " ...простите, но вы читали что он написал?"   Этим все сказано...